# Get parent collection with hierarchy from a child collection

Tags: c#, linq

I m having a problem.

I have a grandchild collection that i d like to turn into a collection of grandparent objects using LINQ. The child objects have a navigation property to parent. I ve tried a group by grandparent name, but then i m stuck with a string.

My grandparent class look like this:

GrandParent class

```
 public class GrandParentBLL
{
    public GrandParentBLL()
    {
        Parents= new List<Parent>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ParentBLL> Parents{ get; set; }

}
```

Child class:

```
Child class

 public class ParentBLL
{
    public ParentBLL()
    {
        Children= new List<Child>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public GrandParentBLL GrandParent { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ChildBLL> Children { get; set; }

}
```

GrandChild class:

```
public class ChildBLL
{
    public ChildBLL()
    {

    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ParentBLL Parent{ get; set; }

}
```

Now i got a list of grandchild objects, where every object can have a different parent or grand parent. I can access the parent with the navigation property. I d like to get a list of grandparent objects with corresponding child collection for each grandparent.

I have tried the following:

```
var grandparents = Children.GroupBy(x => x.Parent.GrandParent).Select(d=>d.Key).ToList();
```

but then i get a grandparent object for every object that is in grandChildren collection, although there are only 2 different grandparents.

Comment: What have you done? Consider adding a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: If you don't include your code and attempt, then this question cannot be answered.

Comment: Always follow this rule: [If your question doesn't include code, are you sure it shouldn't?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: I added some code. Its my first question here.

Comment: Where's the ParentBLL class? Also, why do you need to have separate classes for parent, child, grandparent? Can't you have one class, say a `Person`, and establish the relationships through the properties? So instead of having a `List<GrandChildBLL> GrandChilren ` property, you can have a `List<Person> GrandChilren`, Or simply `List<int> GrandChildrenIds`.

Comment: I ve generated my vode from ADO.net and these classes represent datatables. i was hoping there was a way with LINQ to get the grandParent list with hierarchy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the unique granparent entities, your query should be

```
 var grandparents = grandChildren
                    .Select(c => c.Parent) // --> get all the grand children's parents
                    .Select(p => p.GrandParent) // --> get all the GrandParents from each of the Parents above
                    .Distinct();
```

UPDATE: So base on your comment, as well as the accepted answer, if a parent object doesn't hold the children collection. Here's a way to hydrate your parent objects:

```
IEnumerable<ParentBLL> parents = grandChildren
                       .Select(gc => gc.Parent)
                       .Distinct()
                       .Pipe(p => p.GrandChildren = grandChildren.Where(gc => gc.Parent.ID == p.ID).ToList());

IEnumerable<GrandParentBLL> grandparents = parents
                            .Select(p => p.GrandParent).Distinct()
                            .Pipe( gp => gp.Parents = parents.Where(p => p.GrandParent.ID == gp.ID).ToList());
```

This solution uses `.Pipe`, which "execute the given action on each element in the source sequence and yields it". This is an extension method from [MoreLinq](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ). So you need to add a reference to this package.

Comment: This leaves the parent collection empty. I d like to have grandParent.Parents collection populated.

Comment: Is this a query to a DB using EF? If so, you can use `.Include("Parents")` to populate the navigation property.

Comment: I've updated the solution above based on your comment and the accepted solution. It's an alternative if you don't want to deal with dictionaries and just want to "hydrate" the parent properties with the corresponding children items. So with this, the resulting grandParent items will hold the collection of the related `Parent` objects and each of those Parent objects will hold each of the related `GrandChildren` items.

Comment: This one is perfect. Exactly what i asked for. Ty

Answer (score 1):

### Easy

It's not clear from your example if each class has a collection of its own immediate children. If they do, the answer is easy:

```
Dictionary<GrandParent,List<Child>> results = grandparents.ToDictionary
(
    g => g,
    g => g.Parents.SelectMany( p => p.Children ).ToList()
);
```

### Less Easy

If parents don't know their children, and and only the children know of their immediate parents, there is more work, which I'll take you through in three steps:

Step 1. First get an enumerator for parents, and grandparents that we can re-use:

```
var parents = children.Select( c => c.Parent ).Distinct();
var grandParents = parents
    .Select( p => p.GrandParent )
    .Distinct();
```

Step 2. Now modify the code to change `grandParents` into a `Dictionary<GrandParent,List<Parent>>`:

```
var children = new List<ChildBLL>();
var parents = children.Select( c => c.Parent ).Distinct();
var grandParents = parents
    .Select( p => p.GrandParent )
    .Distinct()
    .ToDictionary
    ( 
        g => g, 
        g => parents.Where( p => p.GrandParent == g )
    );
```

Step 3. Add code to convert `Dictionary<GrandParent,List<Parent>>` into `Dictionary<Grandparent,List<Child>>`:

```
var parents = children.Select( c => c.Parent ).Distinct();
var grandParents = parents
    .Select( p => p.GrandParent )
    .Distinct()
    .ToDictionary
    ( 
        g => g, 
        g => parents.Where( p => p.GrandParent == g )
    )
    .ToDictionary
    (
        pair => pair.Key,
        pair => pair.Value.SelectMany
        ( 
            p => children.Where( c => c.Parent == p ) 
        )
    );
```

When you're done you'll have a dictionary where the key is the GrandParent and the value is a `List<Children>` of its grandchildren.

Comment: Ty, very much. It is not exactly what i was looking for, but it' ll do.

Comment: Can you just please tell me if there is a way to group the grandchildren collection by name but get a collection of grandchild objects. Something like grandChildren.GroupBy(x=>x.Name).Select(d=>d.Key), but to get a collection of grand child objects instead of strings??